# Android - What type of view is shown in the image?

Tags: android, layout

This is android samsund settings. What view shown in the image? Are there card views?

[image: samsung settings]

Comment: I think these are simple Layout with custom drawable background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just simple LinearLayouts set to vertical orientation holding TextViews for the text.  The background is a 9 patch drawable with rounded edges set to stretch.  Add some padding to the top and bottom to make sure the text doesn't overlay it and that's pretty much it.  No special or custom view needed.  The separators can either be views, or they can just be drawables applied to all but the final text view in a group.

Now they may have made a custom view to implement all that and reduce the redundant code.  I would.  But its all standard components.